# How can i get the aws region for my profile in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

I have my aws region configured in the .aws/config for the specific aws profiles.
Is it possible to get the value of the set region (e.g. us-west-1) in my node.js service?
Is there maybe an environment variable that i can read from?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `aws configure get region` to get the region for the default profile.

If you add `--profile` you'll get the region for that specific profile `aws configure get region --profile otherprofile`.

You can use `exec` to run the command from nodejs.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('aws configure get region', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
 const region = stdout

 console.log(region)
})
```

But I think it's better to save the region as an env var and read it from there.